# Python script in InDesign - Index out of range

Tags: python, adobe-indesign

I'm trying out to run Python scripts in InDesign. Python script is triggered by either a .vbs or a .jsx script and the Python code executes correctly. However I'm running into a problem with trying to access items with index of over 255 - it is uniformly over 255. Anything under 255 works fine.

Example (works):

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application.CC.2014')
app.Select (app.ActiveDocument.Stories[0].Characters[100]) //index 100
```

Example (does not work):

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application.CC.2014')
app.Select (app.ActiveDocument.Stories[0].Characters[300]) //index 300
```

There are over 1500 Characters in the Story. The same happens with other DOM objects such as Words or Paragraphs.

The error is uniformly - IndexError: list index out of range

Did anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
app.Select (app.ActiveDocument.Stories[0].Characters[300])
```

with this:

```
app.Select (app.ActiveDocument.Stories[0].Characters.Item(300))
```

Comment: Can't take away the downvote. Upvoted another your question. As for the 'why can't index' — because 'Characters' is one of the internal 'collections' that mimic Arrays, not entirely successfully for some edge cases like this, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how ItemByRange() is supposed to work without normal indexes... I guess I'll try passing actual Character objects as range limiters. Hopefully this will work.